# Arduino Freezing in while loop

Tags: while-loop, arduino

Sorry for the stupid question, I am very basic to this so please go easy on me.

The code seems to run fine, but as soon as there is a missed packet from Arduino 2, Arduino 1 freezes. I believe the signal is momentarily dropping out and the code over the NRF24 is stopping at the while statement.

```
while (!radio.available());                        
radio.read(&TrapAVolt, sizeof(TrapAVolt));
```

is there anyway to over come this, or to restart the loop if a packet isnt there?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte addresses [][6] = {"00001", "00002"};  //Setting the two addresses. One for transmitting and one for receiving
int button_pinA = 2;
boolean button_stateA = 0;
float TrapAVolt;
int i = 1;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button_pinA, INPUT_PULLUP);

  radio.begin();                           //Starting the radio communication
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[1]);     //Setting the address at which we will send the data
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]);  //Setting the address at which we will receive the data
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN); //You can set it as minimum or maximum depending on the distance between the transmitter and receiver.
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print(i);
  Serial.print("    ");
  delay(5);
  radio.stopListening();                             //This sets the module as transmitter
  button_stateA = digitalRead(button_pinA);
  radio.write(&button_stateA, sizeof(button_stateA));  //Sending the data
  Serial.print(button_stateA);
  Serial.print("  Button   ");
  delay(5);

  radio.startListening();    //This sets the module as receiver

  
  while (!radio.available());                        //Looking for incoming data
  radio.read(&TrapAVolt, sizeof(TrapAVolt)); //Reading the data

  Serial.println(TrapAVolt);


  }
  (i)++;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could build yourself a timeout. Maybe like this:

Global definition:

```
#define TIMEOUT 500                            // Timout in milliseconds
```

last part of your loop():

```
int timestamp = millis();                      // Save current time
while(millis() - timestamp < TIMEOUT)          // Check continuously if timeout is reached
{
  if(radio.available())                        // Do nothing until radio data is available
  {
    radio.read(&TrapAVolt, sizeof(TrapAVolt)); // Reading the data
    Serial.println(TrapAVolt);
    break;                                     // Leave loop
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed to an if function and it seems to be working for now. Thanks again